# why all the variables are 'x' during the simulation

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to simulate this module, but during the simulation all the variables 'x's. why ?
is there anything wrong with variable definition and use ?
I'm new at verilog, and I'm not sure if the usage that I did with the variable is right..
this is the module and the test-bench:

```
module viterbi_decoder(
        clock , // Clock input of the design
        reset , // active high, synchronous Reset input
        in_vector ,
        out_vector
        );
        //inputs 
        input clock;
        input reset;
        input [7:0]in_vector;
        //outputs 
        output [7:0] out_vector;
        reg [7:0] out_vector;
        //local variables
        integer index;
        integer row00[4:0];
        integer row01[4:0];
        integer row10[4:0];
        integer row11[4:0];

        integer prev_row00[4:0];
        integer prev_row01[4:0];
        integer prev_row10[4:0];
        integer prev_row11[4:0];

        integer who;
        integer from;
        integer mini;
        integer ham_dist_1;
        integer ham_dist_2;


        reg in[1:0];
        always @ (posedge clock)
        begin 
            if (reset)
            begin
            //reset device
                row00[0] <= 3;
                row01[0] <= 3;
                row10[0] <= 3;
                row11[0] <= 3;
            end
            else
            begin
                row00[0] <= 3;
                row01[0] <= 3;
                row10[0] <= 3;
                row11[0] <= 3;

                for (index=0; index < 8; index = index + 2)
                    //mini([n-1,0],[n-1,1])
                    ham_dist_1 <= in_vector[index] ^ 0 + in_vector[index + 1] ^ 0 + row00[(index / 2)];
                    ham_dist_2 <= in_vector[index] ^ 1 + in_vector[index + 1] ^ 1 + row01[(index / 2)];
                    if (ham_dist_1 > ham_dist_2 )
                    begin
                        row00[index / 2 + 1] <= ham_dist_1;
                        prev_row00[index / 2 + 1] <= 0;
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                        row00[index / 2 + 1] <= ham_dist_2;
                        prev_row00[index / 2 + 1] <= 1;
                    end
                    ham_dist_1 <= in_vector[index] ^ 1 + in_vector[index + 1] ^ 0 + row10[(index / 2)];
                    ham_dist_2 <= in_vector[index] ^ 0 + in_vector[index + 1] ^ 1 + row11[(index / 2)];
                    if (ham_dist_1 > ham_dist_2 )
                    begin
                        row01[index / 2 + 1] <= ham_dist_1;
                        prev_row01[index / 2 + 1] <= 2;
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                        row01[index / 2 + 1] <= ham_dist_2;
                        prev_row01[index / 2 + 1] <= 3;
                    end
                    ham_dist_1 <= in_vector[index] ^ 0 + in_vector[index + 1] ^ 0 + row00[(index / 2)];
                    ham_dist_2 <= in_vector[index] ^ 1 + in_vector[index + 1] ^ 1 + row01[(index / 2)];
                    if (ham_dist_1 > ham_dist_2 )
                    begin
                        row10[index / 2 + 1] <= ham_dist_1;
                        prev_row10[index / 2 + 1] <= 0;
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                        row10[index / 2 + 1] <= ham_dist_2;
                        prev_row10[index / 2 + 1] <= 1;
                    end

                    ham_dist_1 <= in_vector[index] ^ 0 + in_vector[index + 1] ^ 1 + row10[(index / 2)];
                    ham_dist_2 <= in_vector[index] ^ 1 + in_vector[index + 1] ^ 0 + row11[(index / 2)];
                    if (ham_dist_1 > ham_dist_2 )
                    begin
                        row11[index / 2 + 1] <= ham_dist_1;
                        prev_row11[index / 2 + 1] <= 2;
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                        row11[index / 2 + 1] <= ham_dist_2;
                        prev_row11[index / 2 + 1] <= 3;
                    end
                //trace back algorithm
                who <= 00;
                from <= prev_row00[4];
                mini <= row00[4];
                if (row01[4] < mini)
                begin
                    who <= 01;
                    from <= prev_row01[4];
                    mini <= row01[4];
                end
                if (row10[4] < mini)
                begin
                    who <= 10;
                    from <= prev_row10[4];
                    mini <= row10[4];
                end
                if (row11[4] < mini)
                begin
                    who <= 11;
                    from <= prev_row11[4];
                    mini <= row11[4];
                end
                for (index=3; index > 0; index = index - 1 )
                begin
                    if (who == 00 && from == 00)
                    begin
                        out_vector[(index + 1) * 2] <= 0;
                        out_vector[((index + 1) * 2 )- 1] <= 0;
                        who <= 00;
                        from <= prev_row00[index -1];
                    end
                    else if (who == 00 && from == 01)
                    begin
                        out_vector[(index + 1) * 2] <= 1;
                        out_vector[((index + 1) * 2 )- 1] <= 1;
                        who <= 01;
                        from <= prev_row01[index -1];
                    end 
                    else if (who == 01 && from == 10)
                    begin
                        out_vector[(index + 1) * 2] <= 1;
                        out_vector[((index + 1) * 2 )- 1] <= 0;
                        who <= 10;
                        from <= prev_row10[index -1];
                    end
                    else if (who == 01 && from == 11)
                    begin
                        out_vector[(index + 1) * 2] <= 0;
                        out_vector[((index + 1) * 2 )- 1] <= 1;
                        who <= 11;
                        from <= prev_row11[index -1];
                    end
                    else if (who == 10 && from == 00)
                    begin
                        out_vector[(index + 1) * 2] <= 1;
                        out_vector[((index + 1) * 2 )- 1] <= 1;
                        who <= 00;
                        from <= prev_row00[index -1];
                    end
                    else if (who == 10 && from == 01)
                    begin
                        out_vector[(index + 1) * 2] <= 0;
                        out_vector[((index + 1) * 2 )- 1] <= 0;
                        who <= 01;
                        from <= prev_row01[index -1];
                    end
                    else if (who == 11 && from == 10)
                    begin
                        out_vector[(index + 1) * 2] <= 0;
                        out_vector[((index + 1) * 2 )- 1] <= 1;
                        who <= 10;
                        from <= prev_row10[index -1];
                    end
                    else if (who == 11 && from == 11)
                    begin
                        out_vector[(index + 1) * 2] <= 1;
                        out_vector[((index + 1) * 2 )- 1] <= 0;
                        who <= 11;
                        from <= prev_row11[index -1];
                    end
                end
            end
        end

endmodule
```

---

```
`timescale 1ns /1ps
module Testbench;


   reg clock_t;
   reg reset_t;
   reg [7:0] in_vector_t;

   wire [7:0] out_vector_t;

   viterbi_decoder viterbi_1(.clock(clock_t), .reset(reset_t), .in_vector(in_vector_t), .out_vector(out_vector_t));




      initial begin 
      clock_t = 0;
       reset_t = 0;


      end

always #10000 clock_t = ~clock_t; 

always@(posedge clock_t) 
begin

     //case 0
      in_vector_t <= 00110101; // <= 1; reset_t <= 0;
      #5 $display("Result_t = %b", out_vector_t);

      //case 1
      in_vector_t <= 00001111; //clock_t <= 1; reset_t <= 0;
      #5 $display("Result_t = %b", out_vector_t);

      //case 2
      in_vector_t <= 00010101; //clock_t <= 1; reset_t <= 0;
      #5 $display("Result_t = %b", out_vector_t);

      //case 3
      in_vector_t <= 00101100; //clock_t <= 1; reset_t <= 0;
      #5 $display("Result_t = %b", out_vector_t);

      //case 4
      in_vector_t <= 00000000; //clock_t <= 1; reset_t <= 0;
      #5 $display("Result_t = %b", out_vector_t);

   end
endmodule
```

Comment: I fixed the clock issue, but still, everything is 'x'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your test bench needs improvements. The clock is very slow and the dut will only see `in_vector_t <= 00000000;` one the next of any clock edge. I suggest you change your `in_vector_t` in relation to the clock edge. Also since you have a free running clock, you'll need to end the simulation with a `$finish`. Example:

```
always #5 clock_t = ~clock_t;

initial begin
  $monitor("Result_t = %b", out_vector_t);
  @(posedge clock_t) in_vector_t <= 8'b00110101; //case 0
  @(posedge clock_t) in_vector_t <= 8'b00001111; //case 1
  @(posedge clock_t) in_vector_t <= 8'b00010101; //case 2
  @(posedge clock_t) in_vector_t <= 8'b00101100; //case 3
  @(posedge clock_t) in_vector_t <= 8'b00000000; //case 4
  @(posedge clock_t);
  #5 $finish; // end simulation
end
```

In your design, there are may place where you set/compare two bit values to `10` or `11`. These values are in decimal ten and eleven. You need to specify the width and base type, I.E. `2'b10` or `2'b11`. The same is true for your test bench; `00001111` is decimal one thousand one hundred and eleven, `8'b00001111` is decimal fifteen.

You are using non-blocking (`<=`) inside a clocked always block. This is correct. The problem is your code appears to be depended on recently updated values. With non-blocking assignment, the register does not get new value until the end of the time step. Anything sampling/comparing the value will see the old  value until then. In this case you need to split the block into two always blocks: one synchronous using non-blocking (`<=`) and one combinational using blocking (`=`). Not knowing your full intended logic I'll just give you the template to get started:

```
always @* begin : comb_logic__calc_next
   // defaults (constants or flops)
   next_example1 = 8'h00; // constant
   next_example2 = example2;// flop

   /* algorithms for here
    .... made-up example * /
   for (index = 0; index<8; index=index+1) begin
     if (input_bus[index]==1'b1) next_example1[index] = 1'b1;
     else  next_example2[index] = ~next_example2[index];
     if (next_example1[index]==example[7-index]) begin
       next_example2 = {next_example2[6:0],next_example2[7]};
     end
   end
end
always @(posedge clock) begin : synchronous_logic__assign_flops
  if (reset) begin
    // constants only
    example1 <= 8'h00;
    example2 <= 8'h00;
  end
  else begin
    // assign flops to next value
    example1 <= next_example1;
    example2 <= next_example2;
  end
end
```

Beyond that you will need to run simulation with a waveform dumping.